# Can an HTML email body reference a file sent as an attachment (in the same email)?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

Can an HTML email use an image attachment as the source for  tag?

Let's say I am sending an email with per-email specific images - and they are sent as an attachment to the email - can the HTML body within the email use the those images? My guess would be *no*, but are there any *hacks* or workarounds that would make it work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No hacks needed. Use the [`cid:` URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392)

```
 --boundary-example 1
 Content-Type: Text/HTML; charset=US-ASCII

 to the other body part, for example through a statement such as:
 <IMG SRC="cid:foo4*foo1@bar.net" ALT="IETF logo">

 --boundary-example-1

 Content-ID: <foo4*foo1@bar.net>
 Content-Type: IMAGE/GIF
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64

 R0lGODlhGAGgAPEAAP/////ZRaCgoAAAACH+PUNvcHlyaWdodCAoQykgMTk5
 NSBJRVRGLiBVbmF1dGhvcml6ZWQgZHVwbGljYXRpb24gcHJvaGliaXRlZC4A
 etc...

 --boundary-example-1--
```

Comment: I take it the carets are necessary? Content-ID: **<** name **>**

Comment: from the documentation linked to in the answer: "Notes: In Internet mail messages, the addr-spec in a Content-ID
     [MIME] or Message-ID [822] header is enclosed in angle brackets
     (<>)."

Comment: why is the data in base64? It is user defined and needed, or can it be different or inrelevent in that case?