# Send image in mail body

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, email

I want to send image in Mail body not a attachment.

Here is my code.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(""toaddress"));

mail.Subject = strSubject;
mail.Body = "<html><body><img src=cid:companylogo/><br><p>Dear Member,</p>" + strBody + "<br/><b>Regards</b>,<br/>Team</body></html>";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
AlternateView altView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mail.Body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource("logo.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
logo.ContentId = "companylogo";
altView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);
mail.AlternateViews.Add(altView);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(mail);
```

Using this I am getting image as an attachment.

How I will send it as a Mail body?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is to send the image as an attachment, and then refer to int from your mail's HTML. It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983248/can-an-html-email-body-reference-a-file-sent-as-an-attachment-in-the-same-email).

You can also refer to an image from an external server, most modern email clients will allow that.