# Send images in the mail body from unix

Tags: html, unix

I am trying to send an image through html coding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <style>
            body {background-color:blue}
        </style>
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h4>hello</h4>
        <center>
            <img src="C:\Users\dubasir\Desktop\New folder\we.jpg"  width="1200" height="800">
        </center>
        <a href ="http://www.google.com"> This is a linking</a>
        <p>jfklkskflksdlfklsdmklm</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

how to run it unix and get the image in mail body.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you forgot to end the image tag, this is done as follows:

```
<img src="path/blah.jpg" height="100" width="100"/>
```

that slash before you end the tag is needed to close the image tag

Answer (score 0):

You're using an absolute Windows file name for the image. This can't work - the receiving computer has no way to know where on the world that image is stored.

Instead, you need to attach the image to the mail. Give it a name, say `we.jpg`. Now you can use this HTML code to use it in the mail body:

```
 <img src="cid:we.jpg" />
```

Here us an example how the raw mail would look like: [Can an HTML email body reference a file sent as an attachment (in the same email)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983248/can-an-html-email-body-reference-a-file-sent-as-an-attachment-in-the-same-email)