# URL to address a page in a PDF which is in a mail?

Tags: email, url, uri, specifications

I search a way to address a single page in a PDF which is in an email.

Is there an official URL/URI spec which handles this case?

AFAIK there are these steps to get to the page:

1. address the mail.
2. address the pdf attachment in the mail (there could be several attachments in the mail)
3. address page number N in the pdf.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983248/can-an-html-email-body-reference-a-file-sent-as-an-attachment-in-the-same-email/9983277#9983277

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to add a link to a specific attachment in an email, however it *is* possible to [link to a specific page in a PDF externally](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html).

> To target an HTML link to a specific page in a PDF file, add `#page=[page number]` to the end of the link's URL.

If you host the PDFs somewhere instead of sending them as attachments you can get something close to what you want.